# Could not load office add-in

Tags: office-js

I have created a sample manifest file for office add-in. But there are some issues in the xml schema. If I am commenting contents of VersionOverrides with itself the Add-in works fine.

If any one can tell about the issue.

note : The source location and function file is available in my workspace.

Attaching the manifest code.

Thanks
Abhijit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
      <Id>cea85fda-84f6-4278-8d81-74126a2c3870</Id>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
      <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="demo Add" />
      <Description DefaultValue="demo hello"/>
      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="Workbook" />
      </Capabilities>
      <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://localhost:8080</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--EndBasicSettings-->
  <!--BeginTaskpaneMode integration. Office 2013 and any client that doesn't understand commands will use this section.
    This section will also be used if there are no VersionOverrides -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="TableBindings" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
      <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost:8080/excelDemo/Home.html" />
      </DefaultSettings>
      <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
         <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!--Function file is an html page that includes the javascript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called. 
            Think of the FunctionFile as the "code behind" ExecuteFunction -->
          <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopCommnadUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!--Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab -->
            <!-- Documentation includes all the IDs currently tested to work -->
            <CustomTab id="SmartViewAddIns">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->

              <Label resid="residLabel5" />
            </CustomTab>

          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
         </Hosts>
         <Resources>
             <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="icon_login_16" DefaultValue="https://gsmadatahub-dev.corp.apple.com/opf-mac/display/icons/login.png"></bt:Image>
                <bt:Image id="icon_login_32" DefaultValue="https://gsmadatahub-dev.corp.apple.com/opf-mac/display/icons/login.png"></bt:Image>
                <bt:Image id="icon_login_80" DefaultValue="https://gsmadatahub-dev.corp.apple.com/opf-mac/display/icons/login.png"></bt:Image>
             </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost:8080/excelDemo/commands.html" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Test Group" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Execute Function" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane1" />
            </bt:LongStrings>
         </Resources>
      </VersionOverrides>



</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your manifest is that you are using the following line:

`<Label resid="residLabel5" />`

But you do not define the Resource for residLabel5. The manifest only works if you define all Resources that you use.

You can fix your problem when you add the following line to the bt:ShortStrings in your manifest it works.

```
<bt:String id="residLabel5" DefaultValue="Test" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Alex's answer:  in terms of the general case, I recommend you either run your manifest through the validation tool, or use runtime logging to diagnose manifest issues.  See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest for more info.